# Operator overloading in OpenCL kernel

Tags: c++, opencl

I moved from CUDA to OpenCL.

In CUDA I was able to do operator overloading:

```
__device__ bool operator != (const uint2 a, const uint b) 
{ 
    return ((a.x != b) && (a.y != b)); 
}
```

Can I do the same inside OpenCL kernel?

Comment: OpenCL is limited to a subset of C99. Overloading operators is not supported AFAIK.

Comment: No. At AMD's OpenCL I can add -x clc++ to the compiler options. After that I can do, for example, function overloading.

Comment: @atz So you're saying function overloading is a C++ feature and not a C feature?

Comment: Function overloading is not a C feature, but no, this is not the topic

Comment: @atz No matter what proprietary extensions AMD provides, in OpenCL it's generally not possible, as it's written against C99, as talonmies stated correctly. But as you stated yourself that you can enable this in AMD's OpenCL with a compiler option, you seem to be aware of the fact that it is not generally possible and I cannot understand your categorical "No" to talonmies' comment.

Comment: Christian, I think atz simply meant, "No, you cannot overload, but with AMD's compiler you can."

Answer (score 5):

No. The OpenCL kernel language of any current version of OpenCL (1.0, 1.1, or 1.2) is OpenCL C - an extended and subsetted version of C99, which does not feature operator overloading - or for that matter, overloading of user functions either.

It may be that future versions of OpenCL will extend this to have an OpenCL kernel language based on C++, thus permitting operator overloads - but this is not yet standardised or widely available.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if they are still in beta but AMD provides support for it in their latest beta according to this:
  [Key capabilities of OpenCL Static C++ include kernel and function overloading, kernel and member templates, inheritance, friend classes, and more.](http://blogs.amd.com/developer/2012/01/10/amd-opencl%E2%84%A2-app-sdk-2-6-introducing-opencl%E2%84%A2-1-2-preview-and-static-c-kernel-language/)